# linking root of hierarchical clusters with their childs in matlab

Tags: matlab, hierarchical-clustering

I am using hierarchical clustering algorithm to cluster my dataset with different number of clusters. For instance,

```
a= [1;2;3;4;5;20;21;22;28;29]
Z=linkage(a,'ward')
[clusterIndexes]=cluster(Z,'maxclust',2)
```

this snippets clusters data into two at where first cluster holds 1,2,3,4,5. Lets call this cluster A and the second one holds 20,21,22,28,29 which is cluster B.

When I run the following script and cluster data into 3

```
a= [1;2;3;4;5;20;21;22;28;29]
Z=linkage(a,'ward')
[clusterIndexes]=cluster(Z,'maxclust',3)
```

It gives me clusters of (1 2 3 4 5)= cluster X,(20,21,22) = cluster Y,(28,29) = cluster Z.

How can I demonstrate programmatically that cluster B splitted into Cluster Y and Cluster Z?

Sorry for the naive question I am very new to matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setxor` to identify any differences between the two clusters. User `union` to merge `clusterY` and `clusterZ` when comparing to `clusterB`. Since the result is empty the two clusters contain the same set of numbers. If there were any differences between the two it would be output by `setxor`.

```
clusterB = [20 21 22 28 29];
clusterY = [20 21 22];
clusterZ = [28 29];

setxor(clusterB, union(clusterY, clusterZ))

ans =

  1×0 empty double row vector
```

Suppose for example `clusterB` had an additional number, you can see the results below.

```
clusterB = [5 20 21 22 28 29];
setxor(clusterB, union(clusterY, [clusterZ]))

ans =

     5
```